# How can I initialize my datatable in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, datatables

I installed the DataTableBundle in Symfony 4 according to this tutorial: https://omines.github.io/datatables-bundle/#quickstart

DataTableController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\Adapter\ArrayAdapter;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\Column\TextColumn;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\Controller\DataTablesTrait;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class DataTableController extends Controller
{

  /**
  * @Route("/")
  */

  use DataTablesTrait;

  public function showAction(Request $request)
  {
    $table = $this->createDataTable()
    ->add('firstName', TextColumn::class)
    ->add('lastName', TextColumn::class)
    ->createAdapter(ArrayAdapter::class, [
      ['firstName' => 'Donald', 'lastName' => 'Trump'],
      ['firstName' => 'Barack', 'lastName' => 'Obama'],
    ])
    ->handleRequest($request);

    if ($table->isCallback()) {
      return $table->getResponse();
    }

    return $this->render('list.html.twig', ['datatable' => $table]);
  }
}
```

list.html.twig:

```
<!-- in the <head> section -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.2.1/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css"/>


<!-- Insert this where you want the table to appear -->
<div id="presidents">Loading...</div>

<!-- before the closing <body> tag -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.2.1/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>


<!-- Insert this at the end of your body element, but before the closing tag -->
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/datatables/js/datatables.js') }}"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#presidents').initDataTables({{ datatable_settings(datatable) }});
});
</script>
```

But on my page I see only `Loading...`

Comment: So what did your browser js console said? Any errors?

Comment: What `datatable_settings(datatable)` is rendered to in source html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the symfony web profiler to see ajax request.
[image]

Use the web debbuger to see any javascript errors (F12)

Additionally, if you want to load a fake database for dev you should use fixtures

Comment: It works now, I had to run in terminal php assets:install and then clear the cache!

Comment: For completion's sake - this is actually documented under [installation](https://omines.github.io/datatables-bundle/#installation).